# charpits method to solve $u_x^2 + yu_y = u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

$u_x^2 + yu_y = u$ subject to $u(x,1) = 1 +x^2 /4$ for $-\infty < x < \infty $

Setting $p = du/dx$ and $q = du/dy$, I get $p^2 +yq = u$ and so I am able to write the diffeq as $F(p,q,y,u) = p^2 + qy - u = 0 $

Charpits equations then give me:
$dx/dt = 2p$, 
$dy/dt = y$, 
$dp/dt = p$, 
$dq/dt = 0 $, 
$du/dt = 2p^2 + qy$

How would I go about solving these equations in order to find u in explicit form and then find where it is uniquely defined by the data?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see that some equations can be solved directly, $y=y_0e^t$, $p=p_0e^t$, $q=q_0$, and then insert into the remaining equations, $$x=x_0+2p_0(e^t-1),$$ $$z=z_0+p_0^2(e^{2t}-1)+q_0y_0(e^t-1).$$

Now apply $$dz=p\,dx+q\,dy\implies \dot z_0(s)=p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)+q_0(s)\dot y_0(s)$$ along the initial curve $x_0(s)=s$, $y_0(s)=1$, $z_0(s)=u(x_0(s),y_0(s))=1+\frac{s^2}4$ to get $$\frac{x_0}2=p_0\cdot 1+q_0\cdot 0.$$ Using the original equation $p_0^2+q_0=z_0$ gives $q_0=1$. Thus all collected,
\begin{align}
x&=x_0y\\
z=u(x,y)&=1+\frac{x_0^2}4+\frac{x_0^2}4(y^2-1)+(y-1)=\frac{x^2}4+y
\end{align}
etc.

Comment: I think you assumed that $du/dt=2p2+qx$ and not $du/dt=2p2+qy$

Solving $du/dt=2p2+qy$ is $u = p_0^2 e^2t + q_0y_0e^t + u_0$

If $u_0=u(x,1)=1+x^2/4$, how do I find $p_0$ and $q_0$, is $p_0 = x/2$ and $q_0=0$

Comment: Corrected. The initial curve has $x_0(s)=s$, $y_0(s)=1$ and $z_0(s)=1+s^2/4$. Now insert  into $$\dot z_0(s)=p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)+q(s)\dot y_0(s)$$ to find $p_0(s)=s/2$. Then use the original equation to find $q_0(s)=1$.

Comment: when solving $dx/dt = 2p_0 e^t$ we get $x = 2p_0e^t + C_1$ since $x_0 = s$ and $p_0 = s/2$ surely this should give $C_1 = 0$ at t=0 and so the equation for x should be $x = 2p_0e^t $ and not $x=x0+2p_0e^t = s + 2p_0e^t$ as you claim

Comment: Yes, if you integrate $e^t$ you get $(e^t-1)$ etc.

Comment: brilliant thanks